# How can I merge a pandas DataFrame with itself, to have unique labeled rows?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, merge

Given a DataFrame:

```
X =
+---+----------+---------+
|   | Value1   | Value2  |
+---+----------+---------+
| A |    1     |   NaN   |
| A |    2     |   NaN   |
| B |    0     |    0    |
+---+----------+---------+
```

How can I 'merge' it with itself, so as to get rid of two rows with the same label 'A', and  generate this:

```
X =
+---+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|   | Value1   | Value2  | Value1   | Value2  |
+---+----------+---------+----------+---------+
| A |    1     |   NaN   |    2     |   NaN   |
| B |    0     |    0    |   NaN    |   NaN   |
+---+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Why do you wish to do this?

Comment: @BallpointBen The following step is merging DataFrames on the row Index, which does not work well if one DataFrame has repeating ones.

Comment: `pd.merge(left, right, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)` doesn't work?

Comment: @BallpointBen I guess that only works if its only the 'right' dataframe the one with non-unique row indexes. In my case I have a lot of dataframes and cannot check which ones are fine, therefore I need a way to generalize this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a additional key by using `cumcount`

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['newkey']=df.groupby(df['index']).cumcount()
df.set_index(['index','newkey']).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
Out[14]: 
       Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2
newkey      0      0      1      1
index                             
A         1.0    NaN    2.0    NaN
B         0.0    0.0    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: This is great. But the format of the resulting DataFrame is confusing. How can I convert the MultiIndex back to a DataFrame, removing the newkey names?

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x['ind'] = x.index
x['test'] = x.groupby('ind')['Value1'].rank()
x = x[x['test'] == 1][['Value1', 'Value2']].merge(x[x['test'] != 1][['Value1', 'Value2']],
    left_index = True, right_index = True, how = 'outer')
```

Output:

```
   Value1_x  Value2_x  Value1_y  Value2_y
A         1       NaN       2.0       NaN
B         0       0.0       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: You can replace `x['ind'] = x.index; x['test'] = x.groupby('ind')['Value1'].rank()` with `x['test'] = x.groupby(level=0)['Value1'].rank()` where `level=0` indicates you group on the index. For MultiIndexes, you can specify `level=N` where N is the nth level of the MultiIndex.

Comment: Thanks, @coldspeed!